# How to log in to a web page through code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I need to make a super simple web-page monitoring tool in VB.Net that checks FieldNation.com every few minutes for new work orders. To do that, I need to log in to their page. I think I can figure out how to read the page once I'm logged in, but how can I actually log in? I heard it had something to do with WebClient.

Thanks!

-Wyko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use webbrowser control.. it's easier to manipulate its contents

You can go to a website by sing the `Navigate` Method

```
'Put this on your form load or button click event or something like that
    webbrowser.Navigate("http://www.fieldnation.com/")

    Private Sub wb_DocumentCompleted1(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles wb.DocumentCompleted
    If e.Url.ToString = "www.fieldnation.com" Then
        wb.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", username)
        wb.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", password)
        wb.Document.GetElementById("top_login_submit").InvokeMember("Click")
    ElseIf e.Url.ToString = "LoggedIn URL" Then
        'put you code here to get the new work orders
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, that's great! Can I use this code without having an actively displayed webbrowser? I want this to be a tray notifier.

Comment: yes... you can decalre it globally
<pre>Private WithEvents wb as Webbrowser</pre>